# How can I return MySQL results with id's that do not exist in an array of already used id's?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm creating a web-based reading test. The student's receive a random reading passage, and once they answer the questions, the passage id and their student id is placed in a table that tracks which passages they have used.

I need to return the id's of the passages that have not already been used.  I have been trying to use the NOT IN feature of MySQL.

```
$newpassage = "SELECT passName 
               FROM passages 
               WHERE passid NOT IN ('$passidarray');";
```

$passidarray is the array that contains the ids of the passages that have already been used.  But every time, it still returns the passage id that has already been used. I hard coded the numbers to see if it would work and it does.  But the passages they used grows the more they use the test.

For example, if there are three passages and they've only used 1, the result should return 2 and 3, but it is returning 1, 2, and 3. Then once they've used 2, it should only return 3.  But it's returning all of them.  Is there something that I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated or even a better way of doing it.

Comment: You may need to give a snippet of the code where you assign `$passidarray`, because your SQL is valid and will do what you want. So the error must be on the PHP side.

Comment: is your $passidarray imploded with commas...?

Comment: You're probably telling it to look for things not in the string '1, 2' instead of the set (1,2). Try getting rid of the single quotes around it.

Comment: @jprofitt: What it's actually passing is the string 'Array'.

Comment: @amindfv I was going on if he had already imploded.

Comment: @jprofitt: Maybe they're female. But I see what you're saying about the array, haha.

Comment: @Sudhir: No it wasn't imploded, but as amindfv showed me below, I put that in and it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL doesn't use php's array object format. Try:

```
$newpassage = "SELECT passName FROM passages WHERE passid NOT IN (" . implode(',', $passidarray) . ");";
```

Comment: Thank you show much!! That works perfectly. I had tried that once and I think it was only working for the first key in the array. But I think I did not have the () around the whole thing so I gave up on it. But now it works like I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT passName FROM passages WHERE passid NOT IN ('$passidarray')
```

You can't just embed an Array to a string like this. You need to convert the array of values into a string MySQL can understand. For example, if `$passidarray` is

```
array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

you must [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/implode) the array into a comma delimited string.

```
$passidstring = implode(',', $passidarray);
$newpassage = "SELECT passName FROM passages WHERE passid NOT IN ($passidstring);";
```